# Nested JSON in SWIFT 5

Tags: json, swift, xcode, jsondecoder

even though there are many articles about nested json decoding, I'm struggling with following one:

sample from json:

```
{
    "00AK": {
        "icao": "00AK",
        "iata": "",
        "name": "Lowell Field",
        "city": "Anchor Point",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "country": "US",
        "elevation": 450,
        "lat": 59.94919968,
        "lon": -151.695999146,
        "tz": "America\/Anchorage"
    },
    "00AL": {
        "icao": "00AL",
        "iata": "",
        "name": "Epps Airpark",
        "city": "Harvest",
        "state": "Alabama",
        "country": "US",
        "elevation": 820,
        "lat": 34.8647994995,
        "lon": -86.7703018188,
        "tz": "America\/Chicago"
    },
    "00AZ": {
        "icao": "00AZ",
        "iata": "",
        "name": "Cordes Airport",
        "city": "Cordes",
        "state": "Arizona",
        "country": "US",
        "elevation": 3810,
        "lat": 34.3055992126,
        "lon": -112.1650009155,
        "tz": "America\/Phoenix"
    },
    ....
}
```

I start with mapping the airport specifics with following struct:

```
struct Airport : Codable {
    var icao:String
    var iata:String
    var name:String
    var city:String
    var state:String
    var country:String
    var elevation: Double
    var lat: Double
    var lon: Double
    var tz: Double
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case icao
        case iata
        case name
        case city
        case state
        case country
        case elevation
        case lat
        case lon
        case tz
    }
```

}

but I'm stuck - unable to find out how to map a "mother" struct of airport code (00AK, 00AL, 00AZ) and how to look up in decoded data parsed here:

```
let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(AirportsStructToBeCreated.self,
                                                                      from: jsonData)
```

(e.g. how to look up "elevation" of "00AZ")

Answer (score 2):

You have to decode a `[String:Airport]` dictionary

```
let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Airport].self,
                                                                  from: jsonData)
```

or you could implement `init(from decoder` and map the dictionaries to an array as the key is also included in the struct.

And you can omit the CodingKeys if the struct members match exactly the dictionary keys.

And `tz` is **not** Double

Comment: but if use json:  [{
    "icao": "00AK",
    "iata": "",
    "name": "Lowell Field",
    "city": "Anchor Point",
    "state": "Alaska",
    "country": "US",
    "elevation": 450,
    "lat": 59.94919968,
    "lon": -151.695999146,
    "tz": "America\/Anchorage"
}, {...}]
It works with:   let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Airport].self, from: jsonData) ...

Comment: Why do you ask a question about a completely different JSON structure?

Comment: Sorry, it was unnecessary (just tried to exclude other error in rest of the code), I want to use the original structure but your suggested "let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Airport].self,   from: jsonData)" ...gives DECODE ERROR and can't see why..

Comment: What `DECODE ERROR`?

Comment: Sorry again for being unclear: "try" will throw an error

Comment: decodedData is empty and catch just tells me there was an error >> catch {print("decode error") }

Comment: * sigh * **print** the error : `print(error)`. The literal string is meaningless.

Comment: valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "KEDC", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "iata", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: If you get `null` declare the affected property as optional: `var iata:String?`